# How to calculate the ROC when using 10x10 cross validation?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, random-forest, roc

This question is related to this other one :[How to binarize RandomForest to plot a ROC in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244435/how-to-binarize-randomforest-to-plot-a-roc-in-python/44270604#44270604)
And I also use the code available in Scikit: [ROC multiclass problem](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html)

So I want to plot the ROC. But as I am doing a 10x10 cross validation, Do I have to calculate an average of the probabilities ("predict_proba"), as I will be having 100 y_score? And each one is an array of 3x15?

Check this line in the code:

```
y_score = clf.fit(x_train, y_train).predict_proba(x_test)
```

CODE STARTS HERE

```
# Import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Binarize the output
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y.shape[1]

result_list = [] #stores the average of the inner loops - Preliminar
yscore_list = []
clf = Pipeline([('rcl', RobustScaler()),
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)))])

print("4 epochs x subject in test_size", "\n")
xSSSmean84 = [] # 4 epochs x subject =» test_size=84 o 0.1%
for i in range(1):
    sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(2, test_size=0.1, random_state=i)
    scoresSSS = model_selection.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=sss)
    xSSSmean84.append(scoresSSS.mean())

    for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
        x_train, x_test = X[train_index], X[test_index] 
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

        y_score = clf.fit(x_train, y_train).predict_proba(x_test) 
        yscore_list.append(y_score)
        print(y_score)
        print("")
```

This is how y_score looks like. With cross validation I will have many of them:

```
[[ 0.   1.   0.1]
 [ 0.   0.   1. ]
 [ 0.   1.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   1. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   1. ]
 [ 0.   0.   1. ]
 [ 0.   1.   0.1]
 [ 0.   1.   0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   1. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   1.   0. ]]
```

Comment: did I answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look at the meaning of y_score:
each column contains the score for one class
each row  represent one observation.

You might notice that  for StratifiedShuffleSplit (from sklearn documentation):
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html

```
_splits : int, default 10

    Number of re-shuffling & splitting iterations.
```

you are setting this to 2, so you will have only 2 shuffle splits, each of them with 0.1 of the total training size in terms of observations.
Even if the resampling was without shuffling, you would be evaluating your crossvalidation results in <20% of the original data size. Any performance measure you might derive, it will be representative of out-of-sample error only if the 20% obtained from the split is representative of the remaining 80%. I would suggest to start a cross-validation strategy whcih covers the full input dataset as a first step.

Therefore, you do not get a '10x10' cross-validation, but rather you get scores which have a size of:
n

The dataset full dataset size is:

```
Classes     3
Samples per class   50
Samples total   150
```

So when you select 0.1 of the dataset, you will get folds with 15 observations, hence 15 rows in the `y_score`
This explains why you get 15x3 scores.

To derive a ROC, you need to compute false positive and true positive ratios for each of the classes (The ROC is defined only for binary classifiers)

The following code from the link you have sent, should work (columns<->classes)

```
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

From `fpr,tpr` there are different ways you can build a ROC curve multiclass (micro-,macro- averages, see sklearn documentation). hard to advice on this since it really depends from your application/metric of interst.

Still, from any approach you choose you will get multiple ROC curves, one per stratifiedFold.
You can then compute some summary statistics over the AUCs (or TPR,FPRs) of the ROCs of the different folds, e.g. mean, std deviation. That way you can provide an estimate of model performance and their stability on unseen data.